# SqlAlchemy: Refer to the bound session from an object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I am using a declarative object like the following:

```
class MyObject(DeclarativeBase):
   ...
   other_object_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('other_object.id'))
   other_object = relationship("OtherObject")
   ...
```

Suppose I would like to have a convenience method `set_other_object_value`, which would modify `other_object.value`, *creating* an instance of `OtherObject` and adding it to the session, if necessary:

```
def set_other_object_value(self, value):
   if self.other_object is None:
      <create instance of OtherObject and associate with the session>
   self.other_object.value = value
```

The question is: how can I create `OtherObject` and associate it with the session? A possibly equivalent question: is it possible to access the instance of a `Session`, to which `MyObject` was added from within an instance of `MyObject`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`object_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import object_session
# ...

def set_other_object_value(self, value):
    if self.other_object is None:
        value = OtherObject(...)
    self.other_object.value = value
    object_session(self).add(value)
```

But if you have setup you relationships properly, you do not need to add the new `value` to the session, as `sqlalchemy` will figure it out and save it to your database on `commit` anyways.